# Any bounded sequence in $\mathbb R$ has a smallest cluster point $\underline x$ and a greatest cluster point $\overline x$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, limsup-and-liminf

> **Theorem:** Any bounded sequence in $\mathbb R$ has a smallest cluster point $\underline x$ and a greatest cluster point $\overline x$ and they satisfy $\liminf x_{n} = \underline x$ and $\limsup x_{n}=\overline x$.

Could you please verify whether my attempt is fine or contains logical gaps/errors? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

---

To simplify notation, we write $\lim x_{n}$ for $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ and $\limsup x_{n}$ for $\limsup_{n \to \infty} x_{n}$.

Let $(x_{n})$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.

1. We define the limit superior and the limit inferior (if exist) of $(x_{n})$ by $$\limsup x_{n} :=\lim\left(\sup _{k \geq n} x_{k}\right) ,\quad \liminf x_{n} :=\lim \left(\inf _{k \geq n} x_{k}\right)$$

It follows that $$\limsup x_{n}=\inf \{\sup _{k \geq n} x_{k} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}, \quad \liminf x_n= \sup \{\inf _{k \geq n} x_{k} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

2. We call $a$ a cluster point of $(x_{n})$ if every neighborhood of $a$ contains infinitely many terms of the sequence.

---

**My attempt:**

Let $\overline x := \limsup x_{n}$ and $\overline x < \xi$. Then there is some $n$ such that $\overline x < \sup _{k \geq n} x_{k} < \xi$. So $x_k \le \sup _{k \geq n} x_{k} <\ \xi$ for all $k \ge n$ and thus there are finitely many $x_k$ in $(\xi - \epsilon, \xi + \epsilon)$ where $\epsilon := \xi - \sup _{k \geq n} x_{k}$. As such, $\xi$ is not a cluster point of $(x_n)$ and consequently no cluster point of $(x_n)$ is larger than $\overline x$. It remains to show only that $\overline x$ is itself a cluster point of $(x_n)$.

> **Lemma:** If every neighborhood of $a$ contains at least one term of $(x_{n})$ different from $a$ itself, then $a$ is a cluster point of $(x_{n})$.

Given $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $n$ such that $\overline x < \sup _{k \geq n} x_{k} < \overline x + \epsilon$. So there exists some $k \ge n$ such that $\overline x < x_k < \sup _{k \geq n} x_{k}$. As such, $\overline x \neq x_k \in (\overline x  - \epsilon, \overline x + \epsilon)$. By our **Lemma**, $\overline x$ is a cluster point of $(x_{n})$.

Showing that $\underline x :=\liminf x_{n}$ is the smallest cluster point of $(x_{n})$ is similar.

Comment: It's okay, expect that in your lemma, you require that the terms of $x_n$ must be different from $a$ itself. How about the constant sequences or even the convergent ones? The limit should be considered a cluster point too. You can just omit the "different" and then it's alright.

Comment: Hi @lzralbu, 1. If every neighborhood of a contains at least one term of $(x_n)$ different from $a$ itself, then every neighborhood of $a$ contains infinitely many terms of $(x_n)$, thus $a$  is a cluster point of $(x_n)$ by definition. As such, I feel that my lemma is fine.[...]

Comment: @lzralbu [...] 2. If we omit *different from $a$ itself* from my lemma, it becomes "If every neighborhood of $a$ contains at least one term of $(x_n)$, then $a$ is a cluster point of $(x_n)$", which is not correct. For example, take $(x_n)$ where $x_n = n$. Then $a =1$ certainly satisfies "every neighborhood of $1$ contains at least one term of $(x_n)$" [this term is $x_1$], but $a=1$ is certainly not a cluster point.

Comment: It seems you're confusing "terms of a sequence" for "elements of the sequence's image". The sequence $x_{2n}=0$ and $x_{2n-1}=1$ has $0$ and $1$ as cluster points in spite of the neighbourhood $(-0.5, 0.5)$ of $0$ have only one image-value of $x_n$ while having infinitely many (indexed) terms of $x_n$.

Comment: @lzralbu I understand that point, but I think that your modified lemma [If every neighborhood of $a$ contains at least one term of $(x_n)$, then a is $a$ cluster point of $(x_n)$] is not correct as pointed out in my example $x_n = n$ for $n \in \mathbb N$. Could you please confirm this?

Comment: Indeed, it's wrong as phrased and your counterexample is fine. For some reason I thought the lemma should be a restatement of your definition of a cluster point. My bad.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful discussion @lzralbu ;)

Comment: Looks correct to me. A possible (small) suggestion about presentation: I was thrown off by your boxed lemma and I thought you were going to prove it after the box; maybe adding a note like "We will rely on the following lemma to..." might make it clearer.